# How to keep Supervisord running unconditionally?

Tags: linux, daemon, supervisord, long-running-processes, server-administration

In the Supervisord conf files you can specify to autorestart a certain program with:

```
autorestart=true
```

But is there an equivalent for [Supervisord] itself?
What is the recommended method of making sure Supervisord continues running unconditionally, especially if the Supervisord process gets killed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your question is a particular application of the famous "Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?" that is "Who will guard the guards?".

In a modern Linux system the central guarding point is `init` process (the process number 1). If `init` dies, the Linux kernel immediately panics, and thus you have to go to your data center (I mean go afoot) and press `reset` button. There're a lot of alternative `init` implementations, [here](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Comparison_of_init_systems) is one of those "comparison tables" :)

The precise answer how to configure a particular `init` implementation depends on what `init` version you use in that system. For example `systemd` has its own machinery for configure service restart upon their deaths (directives `Restart=`, `RestartSec=`, `WatchdogSec=` etc in a corresponding [unit-file](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). Other init implementations like Ubuntu Upstart also has its analogues ([`respawn` directive](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas) in a service configuration file). Even old good SysV init has `respawn` option for a service line in `/etc/inittab`, but usually user-level services aren't started directly inittab, only virtual console managers (`getty`, `mgetty` etc)

Comment: Thanks. So we are on Ubuntu, and we implemented an init.d script and it seems when we are Killing the supervisord process, that it is not coming back up again. Any idea what are some common causes of init.d not keeping alive daemonized processes?